# Lucene Index | Problem with words having apostrophe!

Tags: lucene

When I do search for the words like Ballantine's, the index gives me the documents that have "'s" only as few search result.

I would like to see only those documents which have the full word Ballantine's as it is in the document.

How could I change my Searching query? Changing index is very diificult for me now. As I've already indexed 3 Million documents. Reindexing takes a lot of time.

Please advice!

Thanks
-Subas

Comment: Which Analyzer did you use for indexing?

Answer (score 1):

You can examine your index if it contains words indexed with "'s" with a took called Luke (requires java runtime): http://www.getopt.org/luke/

Answer (score 0):

One Suggestion - not tested.

1. Dump all your tokens from your index: does it contain 'S' on it's own ?
2. If so, you might be able to build a span-query which looks for "word"+"s" ?